# Feature deactivation error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

I have a chain of features that are connected with a master feature. So when I activate, deactivate master feature on the farm, others get activated sequentially. Now this is giving an error with a feature not existing in my environment, it cannot be found at that scope. Any reason? and how to resolve?

Comment: do you have access to the code? You need to either activate the missing feature or trap / remove the one in question.

Comment: The issue is that I dont have any feature with that id